# Append additional key values to a different <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I've got radios attached to divs, and when the div is clicked the info on the widget updates to display the data associated to the div. I'm getting the data from the Yahoo API with JSON script. The appropriate data is appearing on my div called "Current", but when I click on "24-Hour" I get nothing.

Check out my script on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thetuneupguy/r2Bca/11/

```
$.each(data.query.results.quote, function (key, obj) {
  var $lc = $('<tr/', {
    'class': 'my-new-list'
  }).appendTo('#blk-2 table');
  $lc.append($('<td/>').text(obj.Name || "--"));
  $lc.append($('<td/>').text(obj.PreviousClose || "--"));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I forgot to close out a tag, which I have caught and fixed...

```
var $lc = $('<tr/', {
```

should be...

```
var $lc = $('<tr/>', {
```